# How do i change color of alert buttons in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I started my journey with mobile apps and trying to figure out why my code doesn't change color of alert buttons. Imported `Alert` object and used its props. I am testing this on Android this time.

```js
    <Button
        title="Button"
        color="#ffab1a"
        onPress={() =>
          Alert.alert("My Alert", "My message", [
            { text: "Yes", style: { color: "red", backgroundColor: "green" } },
            { text: "No", style: { color: "red", backgroundColor: "blue" } },
          ])
        }
      />
```

Comment: I believe rather than relying on an Alert and altering its inbuilt feature. Try creating a modal component, and style it as per your will. Make it reusable, in this way, you can keep reusing it wherever you want. And you can have different props as well, to change the color, text etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot customize the default alert which react native provides because they are internally using native alert for both android and ios devices.

For your requiement you have to use use React Native Modalbox, or React Native Modal - both of which provide a highly-customisable modal component.

Comment: This workaround doesn't work. Buttons are still in their default color.